# How to connect sql server using docker on mac?

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker, dbvisualizer

I am trying to connect to sql server using docker. I have successfully enabled the container using this command

```
sudo docker run -d --name aakash -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=Maximus6hero@" -p 1434:1434 microsoft/mssql-server-linux

docker ps
3e41723b93d5        microsoft/mssql-server-linux   "/opt/mssql/bin/sqls…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    1433/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1434->1434/tcp   aakash
```

It shows that my container is running.
But when i try to connect using db visualizer it throws an error.
The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1434 has failed. Error: "The driver received an unexpected pre-login response. Verify the connection properties and check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. This driver can be used only with SQL Server 2000 or later.". ClientConnectionId:6a802ae0-7203-411d-a599-4c1de997d843.

I also have windows pc with me, and i can connect easily using sql server management studio. Even i can connect others pc using that windows pc. But when i try to connect my mac to windows pc using its ip it also gives the same error.

I have enabled tcp/ip connection on windows using sql server configuration manager. But there is no such thing on mac.

Answer (score 1):

You might be getting this error on your MAC because when you run the docker in the background, it uses only 2GB of memory by default which is insufficient to run the SQL server as it needs minimum of 3.25 GB and ideally, we should point it to 4GB of memory. Update the preferences section with above details on your docker. Save and restart the docker and you may check the below steps to see if that might help you for your MAC. I did this using Azure Data Studio and Docker.

Once you have Saved and restart the docker with 4GB of Memory Allocation for docker to run, all you'd need to do is pull the docker image of the sql server and download it. this can be done by below commands on your terminal . FYI, I am using bash commands below:

**Command 1:**

```
sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

This will pull the latest vesion docker image and download. Once done, you need to set your SQL authentication on the server for your database. Follow below commands:

**Command 2:**

```
    sudo docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<SetYourPasswordHere>' \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 \
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
```

This sets your password and uses the port 1433 for SQL server (which is the default port). To confirm if the image has been created and the SQL server is running on docker, execute the below command to check log(s).

**Command 3:**

```
docker ps
```

To check all instances in your history of dockers( i.e. if you already had dockers installed before you are attempting this SQL connection/execution), run the below command and it will give you all the logs of all instances you have created

**Command 4:**

```
docker ps -a
```

or

```
docker ps -all
```

Once, you have completed above steps and see that the docker has created SQL instance, you need to go to Azure Data Studio and set the below credentials to access the server that you just created above using Docker.

```
Server: localhost
Authentication Type: SQL Authentication
Username: sa
Password: <Check Command 2 to see what you entered in the password where it says SetYourPasswordHere>
```

Hope this helps in your tryst with running SQL server on your MAC. All the Best!